# El renderizado de mi función está calculando pero no lo renderiza automático

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usestate, server-side-rendering

Como verán, al agregar dos productos me los trae y en el total muestra perfecto el monto sumado, si yo agrego cantidad no se renderiza el cambio en el total. Si yo vuelvo a compras y luego vuelvo a carrito si está renderizado, pero, ¿Por qué no lo renderiza automáticamente?

[image: imagen]

Les paso mi componente raíz

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { CarritoApp } from "./CarritoApp";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <CarritoApp />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

aca les paso el componente carritoApp

```
import { Navigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { NavBar } from "./components/NavBar";
import { ComprasPage } from "./pages/ComprasPage";
import { CarritoPage } from "./pages/CarritoPage";
import { ProductosProvider } from "./context/ProductosProvider";
import { CarritoProvider } from "./context/CarritoProvider";

export const CarritoApp = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ProductosProvider>
        <CarritoProvider>
          <NavBar></NavBar>
          <div className="container">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<ComprasPage></ComprasPage>}></Route>
              <Route path="/carrito"element={<CarritoPage></CarritoPage>}></Route>
              <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to="/" />}></Route>
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </CarritoProvider>
      </ProductosProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

aca les dejo los dos context juntos ya que son cortos,

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const CarritoContext = createContext()
--------------------------------------------------
import { createContext } from "react";

export const ProductosContext = createContext()
```

por aca le dejo los providers si separados:
carritoProvider.jsx

```
import { useReducer } from 'react'
import { CarritoContext } from './CarritoContext'


const initialState = []

export const CarritoProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const comprasReducer = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case '[CARRITO] Agregar Compra':
                return [...state, action.payload]
            case '[CARRITO] Aumentar Cantidad Compra': 
                return state.map(item => {
                    const cant = item.cantidad + 1
                    if(item.id === action.payload) return {...item, cantidad: cant}
                    return item
                })
            case '[CARRITO] Disminuir Cantidad Compra': 
            return state.map(item => {
                const cant = item.cantidad -1
                if(item.id === action.payload && item.cantidad > 1) return {...item, cantidad: cant}
                return item
            })
                break;
            case '[CARRITO] Eliminar Compra':
                return state.filter(compra => compra.id !== action.payload)
            default:
                return state
        }
    }

    const [listaCompras, dispatch] = useReducer(comprasReducer, initialState)

    const agregarCompra = (compra) => {
        compra.cantidad = 1
        const action = {
            type: '[CARRITO] Agregar Compra',
            payload: compra
        }
        dispatch(action)

    }
    const aumentarCantidad = (id) => {
        const action = {
            type: '[CARRITO] Aumentar Cantidad Compra',
            payload: id
        }
        dispatch(action)

    }
    const disminuirCantidad = (id) => {
        const action = {
            type: '[CARRITO] Disminuir Cantidad Compra',
            payload: id
        }
        dispatch(action)

    }
    const eliminarCompra = (id) => {
        const action = {
            type: '[CARRITO] Eliminar Compra',
            payload: id
        }
        dispatch(action)

    }
    return (

        <CarritoContext.Provider value={{listaCompras, agregarCompra, aumentarCantidad, disminuirCantidad, eliminarCompra }}>
            {children}
        </CarritoContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

aca les paso el productosProvider.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { ProductosContext } from './ProductosContext'


export const ProductosProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [productos, setProductos] = useState([])

    const fetchProductos = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
        setProductos(data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchProductos()

    }, [])

    return (
        <ProductosContext.Provider value={{productos}}>
            {children}
        </ProductosContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Ahora si les paso mis dos componentes, EL PROBLEMA LO TENGO EN CARRITO PAGE, En el renderizado de la funcion calculartotal()
carritoPage.jsx

```
import { useContext } from "react"
import { CarritoContext } from "../context/CarritoContext"

export const CarritoPage = () => {

    const { listaCompras, aumentarCantidad, disminuirCantidad, eliminarCompra } = useContext(CarritoContext)

    const calcularTotal = () => {
        return listaCompras.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price * item.cantidad, 0 ).toFixed(2)
    }

    const handleImpresion = () => {

        print()
    }
 console.log(listaCompras)
 console.log(calcularTotal());

    return (
        <>
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                        <th scope="col">Precio</th>
                        <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                        <th scope="col">Eliminar</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        listaCompras.map(item => (
                            <tr key={item.id}>
                                <th>{item.title}</th>
                                <td>{item.price}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button 
                                    className="btn btn-ouline-primary" 
                                    onClick={ () => disminuirCantidad(item.id)}
                                    >-</button>
                                    <button className="btn btn-primary">{item.cantidad}</button>
                                    <button 
                                    className="btn btn-ouline-primary" 
                                    onClick={ () => aumentarCantidad(item.id)}
                                    >+</button>
                                </td>
                                <td><button
                                    type="button"
                                    className="btn btn-danger"
                                    onClick={()=>eliminarCompra(item.id)}
                                >Eliminar
                                </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    }

                    <th><b>TOTAL: </b></th>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>${calcularTotal()}</td>

                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div className="d-grid gap-2">
                <button 
                className="btn btn-primary"
                onClick={handleImpresion}
                disabled={listaCompras<1}

                >COMPRAR</button>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

comprasPage.jsx

```
import { useContext } from "react"
import { Card } from "../components/Card"
import { ProductosContext } from "../context/ProductosContext"
import { CarritoContext } from "../context/CarritoContext"

export const ComprasPage = () => {

    const { productos } = useContext( ProductosContext )

    const { agregarCompra, eliminarCompra } = useContext(CarritoContext)

    const handleAgregar = (compra) =>{
      agregarCompra(compra)
    }
    const handleQuitar = (id) =>{
      eliminarCompra(id)
    }
   

  return (
    <>
    <h1>Compras: </h1>
    <hr />

    {productos.map(producto => (
        <Card 
        key={producto.id}
        imagen={producto.image}
        titulo={producto.title}
        descripcion={producto.description}
        precio={producto.price}
        handleAgregar={() => handleAgregar(producto)}
        handleQuitar={() => handleQuitar(producto.id)}
        >

        </Card>
    ))}
    
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quitando el llamado a la función calcularTotal() de la tabla, ya debería funcionar.
Quitar esto.

```
<th><b>TOTAL: </b></th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>${calcularTotal()}</td>
```

Y que quede así.

```
 <tbody>
                    {
                        listaCompras.map(item => (
                            <tr key={item.id}>
                                <th>{item.title}</th>
                                <td>{item.price}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button 
                                    className="btn btn-ouline-primary" 
                                    onClick={ () => disminuirCantidad(item.id)}
                                    >-</button>
                                    <button className="btn btn-primary">{item.cantidad}</button>
                                    <button 
                                    className="btn btn-ouline-primary" 
                                    onClick={ () => aumentarCantidad(item.id)}
                                    >+</button>
                                </td>
                                <td><button
                                    type="button"
                                    className="btn btn-danger"
                                    onClick={()=>eliminarCompra(item.id)}
                                >Eliminar
                                </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    }
                </tbody>
...
<p>${calcularTotal()}</p>
```

También podrías guardar el valor del `total` cuando se llame a la función `calcularTotal()` en un estado y mostrar el estado total en el `<p>` anterior.

```
const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
...
<p>${total}</p>
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Deberías intentar lo siguiente.

La siguiente función

```
const calcularTotal = () => {
    return listaCompras.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price * item.cantidad, 0 ).toFixed(2)
}
```

Intenta parametrizarla para evitar problemas con la caché, que es lo que puede estar pasando.

Es decir conviertela a esto.

```
const calcularTotal = (lista) => {
    return lista.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price * item.cantidad, 0 ).toFixed(2)
}
```

Aunque por si acaso también puedes escribirlo así en un arrow function.

```
const calcularTotal = (lista) => lista.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price * item.cantidad, 0 ).toFixed(2)
```

Luego cuando la uses, usala asi

```
<td>${calcularTotal(listaCompras)}</td>
```

Me parece raro que se actualize la cantidad que se muestre pero no la del total. Avísame si te funciona

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con parametrizar?

Comment: No me funciona de ese modo tampoco, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce').

Comment: @FedericoGalassi no será por el " console.log(calcularTotal());" ?